# Ubuntu 10.10 Software Center not responding

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, linux-distributions

I am trying to open the Ubuntu 10.10 Software Center. It's not opening. What could be the issue?

If I try to run Software Center from the terminal I get the following error:

```
kush@kus:~$ software-center

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/apt/aptcache.py", line 105, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(GtkMainIterationProgress())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 130, in open
    self._list.read_main_list()
SystemError: E:Type '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTTP' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 90, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterApp(datadir, xapian_base_path, options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/app.py", line 316, in __init__
    self.view_switcher = ViewSwitcher(self.view_manager, datadir, self.db, self.cache, self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/viewswitcher.py", line 59, in __init__
    store = ViewSwitcherList(view_manager, datadir, db, cache, icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/viewswitcher.py", line 321, in __init__
    self._update_channel_list()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/viewswitcher.py", line 395, in _update_channel_list
    self._update_channel_list_installed_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/view/viewswitcher.py", line 448, in _update_channel_list_installed_view
    if (pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/apt/aptcache.py", line 128, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use Medibuntu and my internet was creating the problem.
Due to this: Ubuntu Software Center , Synaptic Package Manager & Update Manager had 
stopped working.

After some research over internet it appeared that Issue was with medibuntu list due to internet.

Solution that worked was simply deleting the file from source list located at: **/etc/apt/sources.list.d**